# Generate dynamic page from json data through URL in Wordpress

Tags: json, wordpress, dynamic

I'm rather new in Wordpress developing and here is what I'm trying to do.

I've developed a plugin that retrieves and displays a very few details from JSON objects on a Wordpress page via a shortcode, a kind of list. I want to get more details from each item in the list on a single page when clicking on the items. So that I can get a dynamic page which could display more data from every single object of the list through a get parameter. The get parameter would be the object ID so that I can query it from my JSON source. I don't know if I make myself clear =/

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try any code script?

Comment: No I didn't. I mostly wanted to know in which direction I should go.